# How to build a regular expression in PHP, containing alphabetic and accent/circumflex/etc characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have never worked with regular expressions. And now, at my job, I need a regular expression that accepts a string with:

(It is a full name that can have so many variants and many languages)

- Blank spaces
- Any quantity of numbers
- Any quantity of alphabetic characters, including grave, acute, circumflex, tilde, diaresis, ring above, cedilla, etc. This is all variants of each letter. Example (A, À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å)
- Latin special characters (ñ Ñ, ç Ç)
- German special character (ß)
- En dash (-)

I am reading and studying documentation now, but I am stuck.

Comment: You can find some infos here https://regex101.com/

Comment: *Stack Overflow Wouldn't Be Very Welcoming*. Show your attempts.

Comment: You want a regex that matches anything? Or what should it not match, I can't see what is not allowed

Comment: unclear input and output required from regular expressions validations.

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow is for questions when you have searched before information and show what you have done before, but I really have no idea and it was so urgen. Really sorry for this question, but I know that this comunity answers very fast and this is the reason because I try to stay there. This is my first question of that kind.

Comment: Anyone of you knows any "I need fast help" comunity for that kind of questions? My coworker left the work yesterday and he was the expert on the regular expressions. My territory are JQuery plugins and PHP libraries, and now I have mi back exposed. So until my boss hires a new PHP specialist I need to stay there. Could you please give me more info where can I find the best documentation about regular expressions?

Comment: @Jordi: volunteers usually don't respond to ASAP/urgent/fast questions, as they are effectively a request for priority treatment over other people who also want help ([see here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)). If you don't have the necessary support at work, it should be OK for you to approach your boss and ask for it. You can't be expected to know everything, and if someone has left, it is up to your boss to provide temporary respite. They could hire a local freelancer, or give you a budget to get immediate private support with an hourly-rate video-conference contractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
^[0-9\wÀ-ž\s\-]+$
```

- `0-9` for numbers
- `\w` for word characters
- `À-ž` for the special characters
- `\s` for spaces
- `\-` for the `-`

wrapping this inside `[]` makes an class, which maches everything inside and putting a `+` after the class, says at least one element of this character class.

Comment: In addition to that `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter of any language